# Startup, Shutdown, and applying computer settings?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, shutdown, group-policy, delay

At work, I login to my computer (XP) using domain.

It takes long time at "running startup scripts", long time at "running shutdown scripts" and ages at "Applying computer settings".

I checked local computer policy and there are no scripts for the local computer.

1- How can I see the domain startup/shutdown scripts? I want to know what do they do on my computer :)
2- What does windows do at the really-long "Applying computer settings"?

EDIT:
it is Company laptop.

Comment: Do you have access to look at/edit group policy on your domain?  One check that may give some clues would be to open up a command prompt and enter gpresult to get general information about your gpo's.

Comment: Also check event viewer logs to see if you are able to find any other clues.

Comment: Is this a company PC or a PC you own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ask your IT department about the settings they enforce with Group Policy. If you feel the delay is affecting your work, let them know. They may be perfectly willing to let you know what is going on. But understand that they are often told by people higher in the organization what policies to enforce on the computer you are using.

Second, be aware that startup and logon times may be slower when you are not connected to your company network.

Third, open a command prompt and run:

```
gpresult /v >gpresult.txt
```

then open `gpresult.txt` in Notepad to see the settings that are being applied. The list may be long. This may show you filenames for scripts that run, but you will not be able to see the contents of the scripts.

Comment: I like that gpresult command, nice find.

Comment: I ran gpresult, it is gr8! I looks like I have lots of policies applied!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to see what the log in scripts are running at the server level unless you have access to the netlogin folder on a domain controller. I can tell you that during the "applying computer settings" phase it is not running a login script. You may see the login script popup as cmd window quickly when you finally get access to the desktop (I believe this depends on whether or not they have @echo off in the script).

Do you know if you have [roaming profiles](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Roaming_user_profile)? It's possible it is updating your profile when you log in and out during that period of time. If not, I noticed that if I turn my wifi off or unplug my ethernet cable so the PC is unable to contact a login server it will revert to cached credentials and log in much faster.

Comment: +1 for roaming profiles.. those things are such a dog!